# data start/end with 0 (string) recognized different data when using Pandas query

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, compare

I'd like to read 2 CSV files and compare them.
I need to process the data so I read them as string.
To compare, I use query of Pandas and output not macthed rows.

When I have a data in row that starts with 0 and ends with 0, it is recognized as not matched although they are exactly the same data.
Do you have any idea why it is recognized as different data?

data

```
csv_1
id, id_2, name, unit, dep, sales, code, others
1, 22, apple, 100, 243837463, 89.90, 0214008000000, 88899
2, 23, orange, 403, 111839281, 10.10, 7474836251038465, 80000

csv_2
id, id_2, name, unit, department, sales, special_code, others
1, 22, apple, 100, 243837463, 89.900, 0214008000000, 88899
2, 23, orange, 403, 111839281, 10.10, 7474836251038465, 80300
3, 24, banana, 909, 784635281, 30.17, 6241325251038465, 80000
```

code

```
    df1 = pd.read_csv(csv_1, header=0, dtype=str, na_filter=False)
    df2 = pd.read_csv(csv_2, header=0, dtype=str, na_filter=False)
    df_1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    df_2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    df1 = df_1.applymap(str.strip) #trim
    df2 = df_2.applymap(str.strip) #trim
   ....other data processing


    dfx = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['id', 'id_2'], right_on=['id', 'id_2'], suffixes=['_data1', '_data2'])
    print(dfx.query('name_data1 != name_data2'))
    print(dfx.query('unit_data1 != unit_data2'))  
    print(dfx.query('dep != department'))
    print(dfx.query('master_jan != jan_dh'))  
    print(dfx.query('sales_data1 != sales_data2'))  
    print(dfx.query('code != special_code')) 
    print(dfx.query('others_data1 != others_data2'))
```

output

```
    name_data1 unit_data1 dep... code... 
1   apple, 100, 243837463...0214008000000
```